# ag-grid set the column header to be a checkbox,and do the select all or deselect all column,other than only groups

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

when using ag-grid, I want to set the first column header to be a checkbox,and do the select all or deselect all column action on all rows other than only groups.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71927373/why-apply-button-does-not-work-in-ag-grid-filter-agsetcolumnfilter?newreg=045dbe3d88d44f13b51fefcf208d83ce Maybe this will be of some help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In gridOptions:

```
angularCompileHeaders: true
```

Where you are defining your columns, define the first column as such:

```
{
   field: 'RowSelect',
   headerName: ' ',
   checkboxSelection: true,
   suppressMenu: true,
   suppressSorting: true,
   headerCellRenderer: selectAllRenderer
 },
```

In that file define the renderer:

```
function selectAllRenderer(params) {
    var cb = document.createElement('input');
    cb.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');

    var eHeader = document.createElement('label');
    var eTitle = document.createTextNode(params.colDef.headerName);
    eHeader.appendChild(cb);
    eHeader.appendChild(eTitle);

    cb.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        if ($(this)[0].checked) {
            params.api.selectAll();
        } else {
            params.api.deselectAll();
        } 
    });
    return eHeader; 
}
```

Please note that the creator is currently working on making this a feature, but this is the current work-around. Check here for updates and a more generic non-angular version: [selectAll Feature Discussion](https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/issues/46)

Comment: Can u provide a fiddle or plnkr for this. I am trying this with ag-grid-vue, but not successful

Comment: The creator updated the framework to have an option for this now, so it is no longer necessary to follow my custom advice. See the discussion link I posted above and look at "ceolter commented on Feb 8, 2017
this item is now done. the next release (coming days) will have header checkbox selection."

Answer (score 8):

Should anyone come here looking for answers this feature is already in ag-grid, just place `headerCheckboxSelection: true` in your column's definition.

See docs [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/row-selection/?#header-checkbox-selection)

Comment: The suggestion in this answer will put a checkbox in the column header. To also put it in every row, include "checkboxSelection: true" as well. There's a grid option (rowSelection) that determines if you can select more than one row at a time with the checkboxes.