# Why Apply Button does not Work in Ag-grid Filter (agSetColumnFilter)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am trying to use Apply and Reset button with agSetColumnFilter in my application but it does not work as expected.

Scenario: When we try to add some text in the search box and click on Apply it does not filter. I have added a [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/FEdDiNdTOZEiUTH0?preview) feel free to modify.

```
    { field: 'country', filter: 'agSetColumnFilter', 
      filterParams: {
          buttons: ['reset', 'apply']
      }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You're using the filtering incorrectly. If you want to select only Australia and Austria for example, you should first deselect "(Select All), search for "Aus", then tick Australia and Austria.

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing. Using the "Apply" button doesn't work. However pressing "Enter" on the keyboard seems to work. I believe this is a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to AgGrid documentation, If you want the same behavior then you have to add `'excelMode': 'windows'` in the filterParams.

```
columnDefs: [
  // set filters
  { 
    field: 'athlete',
    filter: true,
    filterParams: {
      buttons: ['reset', 'apply'],
      excelMode: 'windows',
    },
  },
]
```

Below links are given for your reference.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/filter-set-excel-mode/#example-excel-mode

Working code as expected:
https://plnkr.co/edit/iZQa3eeJu807zlj3?preview